# max frequency of character in string

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<cstring>
#define arraySize 10

using namespace std;
char returnMaxOccur(char *str);

int main()
{
    char str[]="teet";
    cout<<"The max occuring character is"<<" "<<returnMaxOccur(str)<<endl;
    return 0;
}

char returnMaxOccur(char* str)
{
    int high=-1;
    char t;
    int counter[arraySize]={0};

    int len=strlen(str);

    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        counter[str[i]]++;
    }


    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(high<counter[str[i]])
        {
            high=counter[str[i]];
            t=str[i];
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

In the following question when  `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` 
is included the results for input string are as follows,

```
1)teet: ans is t  
2)eett: ans is e  
3)ttee: ans is t  
4)ette: ans is e
```

but when i include `#include<iostream>` 
instead of `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` 
the results are

```
1)teet: ans is e  
2)eett: ans is t  
3)ttee: ans is t  
4)ette: ans is e
```

what is the reason for this behaviour,or am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: `str[i]` is way larger than `arraysize` (10) -> you are invoking *undefined behavior*

Comment: Use std::string for strings. Use std::map<char,int> to count

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a textbook case of how undefined behaviour can manifest in seemingly bizarre behaviour.

In practice, including different headers has likely affected what bytes are at certain positions in memory, bytes that you accidentally observe when you *vastly* overrun your array `counter` (size 10) with indexes that could go all the way up to 255.

The traditional way to approach this task is with a `std::map<char, int>`, which can effectively function as a "sparse array". Failing that, just make sure you have enough "slots" in your `int[]` for every possible input.

(And, IMO, [you shouldn't be using `bits/stdc++.h` *anyway*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).)

Answer (score 1):

The first important thing is that your code is not correct. Please correct it as follows:

Instead of

```
#define arraySize 10
```

use

```
#define arraySize 128
```

as `str[i]` may be arbitrary character (I suppose an ASCII character from `0` to `127`)

and only then repeat your testing with changing the `#include` statement.

The second - and generally more important - was just expressed by [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96) in his link ([Why should I not #include ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h))

Comment: This will help little when `str` contains letters (as in the OP's case).

Comment: @Angew - I don't understand you - it changes incorrect code (out-of- bounds index) to the correct one in spite of symbols used in `str`. Note apostrophes around `0` in my replacement.

Comment: `'t' - '0' > 9`, [see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3eaf43ca174ecf0). Your fix would only help if `str` was restricted to digits.

Comment: @Angew - Oh, you are right, thanks! I am going to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

when `i=0`, `counter[str[i]]++` is `counter[116]++`, but counter array size is 10. So the code `counter[116]++` modifies an arbitrary memory address.